# Unable to visit multiple pages in chrome using chrome.tabs.query - Chrome extension script

Tags: javascript

I want chrome extension to visit multiple URLs that I passed but it just visited first 2 URLs and stopped.

Not sure is it a right approach or a better approach to visit multiple URLs one by one.

My requirement is will get list of URLs and extension should visit one by one and read data from it.

Here's what I tried

````
     console.log("test button clicked");
     let urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/HP-Cartridge-Black-3YM57AN-Tri-Color/dp/B08412PTS8/ref=lp_16225007011_1_3?sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D", "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B6PMR9WC/ref=sspa_dk_detail_4?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B0B6PMR9WC&pd_rd_w=4TLRL&content-id=amzn1.sym.386c274b-4bfe-4421-9052-a1a56db557ab&pf_rd_p=386c274b-4bfe-4421-9052-a1a56db557ab&pf_rd_r=4RHFAW0P8YHV8XF2RVKN&pd_rd_wg=kteSY&pd_rd_r=3baa8c92-31ab-4870-bbd3-ce1729f1eab8&s=office-products&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWxfdGhlbWF0aWM&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRFE4NkM1SVJUSjZYJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDE2NjM5MjhTVU5BN0Y3WkxOSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNTc3NDAyM1FGSllBM0w4UTdPUSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbF90aGVtYXRpYyZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=", "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CJXY75BL/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B0CJXY75BL&pd_rd_w=8gExc&content-id=amzn1.sym.a53ea610-e450-44d1-897e-68c0c718bf50&pf_rd_p=a53ea610-e450-44d1-897e-68c0c718bf50&pf_rd_r=5XZHE9A9YTCPHYME65X6&pd_rd_wg=2QxpH&pd_rd_r=be3e2994-be76-4e2a-9784-0292453a1d42&s=office-products&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWxfdGhlbWF0aWM&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExN0FGRUtMVzBLNDI5JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzIyMzIyMTA4UTFZSzJSTUJYNyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNzM2ODgzMUNBWFNVQTRWVVdTTSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbF90aGVtYXRpYyZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=#customerReviews"]
     for(var i=0;i< urls.length; i++){
         console.log(urls[i]);
         await chrome.tabs.update({
             url: urls[i]
        });
        let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
         let html_content = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
             target: { tabId: tab.id },
             func: getAmazonData
         })
         let data = html_content[0].result
         //await chrome.storage.local.remove("amazon.com")
         let getData = await chrome.storage.local.get("amazon.com")
         console.log(getData);
         console.log(getData['amazon.com']);
         if (getData['amazon.com'] === undefined) {
             console.log("Pushed for first time");
             await chrome.storage.local.set({ "amazon.com": [data] })
             let est = await chrome.storage.local.get("amazon.com")
             console.log(est);
         }
         else {
             let getLData = await chrome.storage.local.get("amazon.com")
             console.log(getLData);
             console.log("Pushed for more than one time");
             let latestData = getLData['amazon.com'];
             console.log(latestData);
             latestData.push(data)
             console.log(latestData);
             let setNewData = await chrome.storage.local.set({ "amazon.com": latestData })
             await updateNotifyCount()
         }
     }    
})```
````